# How to change the Mail "Archive" folder for email account/s?

Tags: email, archive

On OS X 10.8.3, in Mail, is there a way  to change the account folder that the "Archive" button sends the mail messages to?
For example, on GMail it should go into "All Mail".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/581196/101610).

1. Close Mail;
2. Go to `/Users/<username>/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/`;
3. Edit `Accounts.plist` (make a backup just in case);
4. Find the key-string pair:
   `<key>ArchiveMailboxName</key>

   <string>Archive</string>`
5. Change the `<string>` tag value to your desired archive folder name, e.g. `[Gmail]/All Mail` or `All Mail` depending on your account folder naming scheme.
6. Save the file;
7. Reopen Mail

The Archive folder(s) will now apear with their own icon on the left pane and not as regular folders.

You can also add an archive button to the toolbar.

Comment: Make sure to do this to correct account. The first archive mailbox name listed may be for the local account or some other account. You can verify the account name by searching for the AccountName key in the dict block.

Answer (score 0):

And if you'd like to turn off archiving all together, setting this string to "NO" seems to work

```
<key>HasServerDefinedArchiveMailbox</key>
<string>NO</string>
```

Be aware, a program update from Apple might undo these changes.