# How to change the Mail “Archive” folder for email accounts in El Capitan

Tags: mail.app, archive

I have set the Apple Mail "Archive" folder to something custom in the past with the help of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89448/how-to-change-the-mail-archive-folder-for-email-account-s).  However, the  folder that I was previously using is "stuck" as the Archive folder, and my efforts to set them to a new year (I use Archive/{year}) make no difference.

In El Capitan (10.11) it seems that they've changed how settings are stored so my changes to the `~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Accounts.plist` appear to be being ignored.  I've had a good dig around the new(?) `~/Library/Mail/V3/` and resulting `~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/` folders, to no avail.

Unfortunately I'm poking around blindly, so I hoped that somebody here might help.

Comment: I stumbled upon the same issue. I posted a corresponding question at https://discussions.apple.com/message/29583222#29583222.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under **OS X El Capitan** (tested with Mail 9.2), you can set it directly within the Mail application:

1. Select your *new* archive folder.
2. From the menu, choose **Mailbox > Use This Mailbox As > Archive Mailbox**

In German, it is **Postfach > Dieses Postfach verwenden als > Postfach "Archiv"**.

Edit: Apparently at Apple they realized, that the menu location in El Capitan wasn't ideal and so they changed it again.

Under **macOS Sierra** (tested with Mail 10.1), you can still set it directly within the Mail application:

1. From the menu, choose **Mail > Preferences > Accounts > *Select your account on the left* > Mailbox Behavior**

In German, it is **Mail > Einstellungen > Accounts > *Links den betreffenden Account auswählen* > Postfach-Verhalten**.

Comment: legend!  works perfectly

Comment: Unfortunately, in Mail 11.3, I don't see any option to set the Archive folder under the `Mail > Preferences > ... > Mailbox Behavior` settings. My email account is an Exchange one, maybe the problem comes from that.

Comment: @MichaëlPolla, you are right, it is because of the Exchange account. It still works with IMAP but the settings do not appear for Exchange accounts.