# Define Archive Folder in different account

Tags: mail.app, email, macos, gmail, archive

Following the question, [How to change the Mail “Archive” folder for email accounts in El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222132/how-to-change-the-mail-archive-folder-for-email-accounts-in-el-capitan):

I have several mail accounts in macOS Sierra and would like to archive all mail in one folder in one specific account. It seems that I am only able to archive them in an Archive folder in the respective account.

Is this true? Can I set one Archive account (Gmail / All Mail folder) for all accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Mail won't move messages between entire accounts for these kinds of automated actions.

However, multiple accounts can choose the On My Mac location, which removes the messages from the account into a single location. This isn't synchronised though.

You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html